# pcolor plot force color limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am making a plot using plt.pcolor(numpy.matrix)

The values in the matrix are fixed, they only can be 0,1,2,3 or 4.

However, when I make the plot, the color limits are wrong.

I am showing the color margins on this picture.

```
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['blue','green','red','black','yellow'])
plt.pcolor(matrix, edgecolors='black', linewidths=1,cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

So, I would like to force matplotlib to take:

```
blue=0
green=1
red=2
black=3
yellow=4
```

How can I achieve that?

Even if in the matrix there is not any value `3` but there are some `4s` I still would like to keep the color coding.

**EDIT:**

I did an small improvement by using:

```
plt.clim(0,4)
```

However still not 100% ok.

Comment: Try specifying vmin=0 and vmax=4, or maybe vmin=-0.5 and vmax=4.5, in your call to pcolor.  And when you say "not 100% ok", what exactly is wrong with the output (since you don't show it)?

Comment: @newPyUser did you solve this problem ?

Comment: nope!, just left it and tried with any other plot