# Customizing colors in matplotlib - heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap

How can I specify colors in heatmap. 
In this example, the data are uniquely one of 4 values `{0,1,2,3}`

```
Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

data= [[ 0, 3, 1, 1],[ 0, 1, 1, 1],[ 0, 1, 2, 1],[ 0, 2, 1, 2],[ 0, 1, 1, 1]]
print data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=Index, columns=Cols)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(np.array(data))
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

How can I specifiy those colors in a way to represent 
    colors= {0:'green',1:'red',2:'black',3:'yellow'}

Comment: How are you currently plotting your data? What function are you using? Can you add the code?

Comment: Thanks! @Ffisegydd I use pcolor to build heatmap. Code has been updated!

Comment: It's similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229152/pcolor-plot-force-color-limits

Answer (score 12):

Create custom colormap and set ticks to your integers

```
from matplotlib import colors
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green','red','black','yellow'])
bounds=[-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(np.array(data), cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(heatmap, ticks=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Is this what you want?
Notice, that your `data` are displayed "upside down".
[image: listed colormap]

Answer (score 2):

I modified this code to show 3 red / yellow / green states of 9 nodes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors 
import LinearSegmentedColormap
colors = [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0)]  # Red, yellow, green
n_bins = [3]  # Discretizes the interpolation into bins 
cmap_name = 'my_list' 
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, colors, N=3)
threshold = 3  # max value
data = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 2]]
img = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', vmax=threshold, cmap=cm)
plt.show()
```