# Visualize a co-occurrence matrix in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have calculated an array with how many % of the total number of permutations contain all different pairs combinations. Now I want to visualise this as for example a heat map. I have the following code for calculation:

```
#occurrences matrix
a = np.array(np.array_split(np.random.binomial(1,.5,30),10), dtype='f')

#co-occurrences matrix
acov=np.dot(a.T, a)
acov[np.diag_indices_from(acov)]=0
acov /= acov.sum()
```

And then i try this for visualisation:

```
plt.imshow(acov,interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

However I dont really know what im doing, first time I use a heatmap so not sure what im seeing. What I would like is a graph with the same shape as the array where each square has a colour intensity representing how large it is on a scale from 0-1.

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
plt.imshow(acov,interpolation='nearest', cmap='Reds')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

using [seaborn.heatmap()](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
sns.heatmap(acov)
```

[image]

Comment: Would like not to have to add another dependency since i have pyplot already.

Comment: then you may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578648/customizing-colors-in-matplotlib-heatmap)

Comment: @user3139545, do you have `pylab` module installed?

Comment: i did try seaborn and it is exactly what i want, for your next example i dont understand what the x and y axes are acually showing? Why -0.5 to 2.5?

Comment: and why a 6x6 matrix and not a 3x3?