# How can I use the matplotlib to draw this picture?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use grid to achieve this. However, I have encountered many problems with color fills and axes。I refer to an example in the official matplotlib documentation that is very close to this image
[image]
（[the link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/image_zcoord.html#sphx-glr-gallery-api-image-zcoord-py)), but it's still a little different.

here is the picture
[image]

It's my fault, the picture is too large，it's difficult to implement quickly. So i choose a part of the original image， here：

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Could you show your work?  What have you already done and exactly where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Try with plotting [custom heatmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578648/customizing-colors-in-matplotlib-heatmap). For example

```
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['cyan','gray','white','yellow'])
bounds=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

data=np.array([[5,15,5],[25,32,6],[15,31,25]])
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.show()
```

a value between **0-10** will give **cyan** colour, **10-20** will give **gray** as so on. So make your data array accodingly.

Result :

[image: Heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this qusetion by using seaborn.

```
from matplotlib import colors
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white','gray','blue','yellow'])
bounds=[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
data = np.array([[1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5], [1,1,1,3,1,1,1,5], [1,1,1,1,1,1,3,5]])
ax = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, linewidths=.5, 
linecolor='black', square=True, cbar=False)
sns.plt.annotate('S', (1.4, 3.4))
sns.plt.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taVyd.png)